# Java raw type value assigned to generic type run time getClss() method error

Tags: java, generics, casting, runtime

```
public class Box<T> {
    private T t;
    public Box(T t){
        this.t = t;
    }
    public void add(T t) {
      this.t = t;
    }
    public T get() {
      return t;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Box<Integer> b = new Box(new String("may be"));
      System.out.println(b.get()); // successfully print out "may be"
      System.out.println(b.get().getClass()); // error
   }
}
```

This code gives a runtime error:

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

1. why is `b.get()` not triggering a runtime error?
2. why does an runtime error occur only when I try to get the class of the class variable?

To be more precise: why is the compiler inserting a `checkcast` instruction into the bytecode **only** for the *second* `get()` (leading to the exception)?

Comment: im assuming `get` just gets you a pointer to SOME object and in your example invokes `toString` on it, but `getClass` actually checks and resolves the type. you expect an `Integer`, but the object is a `String`, so `getClass` internally casts it and fails.

Comment: @GhostCat much more clear!

Comment: @GhostCat go for it. I don't mind it at all. Thanks for the improvement

Comment: @GhostCat yes it inserts it for the second `get` because the typecheck comes from `getClass`. the first line doesnt throw an exception because `toString` is implemented by all `Object` types. any method you invoke that tries to resolve the types will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note:

- in the first case, the result of `get()` is used for `println(Object)`: in other words: the receiving side expects an Object, and that "condition" will always be true.
- in the second case, a **method** invocation on the returned object will follow. And now it makes can make a **huge** difference if the returned type is the **expected** one. Therefore the compiler is adding this check to guarantee that the following method call is **sound**.

As background, one can look into the Java Language Specification, chapter 5.52:

> The cast is a checked cast.
>
> Such a cast requires a run-time validity check. If the value at run time is null, then the cast is allowed. Otherwise, let R be the class of the object referred to by the run-time reference value, and let T be the erasure (§4.6) of the type named in the cast operator. A cast conversion must check, at run time, that the class R is assignment compatible with the type T, via the algorithm in §5.5.3.

respectively chapter 5.53 [Checked Casts at Run Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.3).

Comment: the return type expected is `Class<T>` and it would make no sense to  return a `Class<String>` when it was declared as `<Integer>` hence the cast

Answer (score 2):

This variable declaration is inconsistent.

```
  Box<Integer> b = new Box(new String("may be")); :
```

The instantiated object is raw, so the compiler emits a warning about it but allow to assign the raw type to a generic variable :  `Box<Integer>`.

`b.get()` doesn't fail as you don't assign the result to a variable.
So the compiler doesn't need to cast it to anything.

Try that :

```
Integer value = b.get();
```

It will compile fine but you will get the same exception at runtime as 
the JVM will try to cast the value to `Integer`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

---

When you invoke :

```
System.out.println(b.get().getClass()); // error
```

Things are are close to.

**Why the `Integer` class is expected here ?**

At compile time, `b` is declared as `Box<Integer> b`.
So the compiler knows that `b` is parameterized with a `Integer` type.
So yes after compilation, generics are erased but the compiler adds however some casts according to the declared code.

And this is the case here.
You invoke `getClass()` on a variable that is parameterized with `Integer`. 
But `Class` is a generic class : `Class<T>`.
 So a cast to `Integer` was added by the compiler to conform to `Class<Integer>`.

Of course, by using generics both for the variable declaration and instantiation :

```
  Box<Integer> b = new Box<>(new String("may be"));
```

this kind of inconsistency is not possible as the compiler stops you right now.

Comment: why getClass() is different from get() in that getClass() will do the cast while get() will not cast but just return whatever the object is? In this case even though get() is meant to return a Integer according to the declaration, but it actually returned a String without causing problem, while getClass() does care what type it returns? Thanks for the answer just needed a bit of clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the answers here, the byte instruction `checkcast` gets called on typechecks which are not the concrete type of `Object`. For example

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
          Box<Integer> b = new Box(new String("may be"));
          doStuff(b.get()); // no checkcast needed - works fine
          doIntegerStuff(b.get()); // run-time error with checkcast
          doStringStuff(b.get()); // compile error
       }

 public static void doStuff(Object object){}
 public static void doStringStuff(String integer){}
 public static void doIntegerStuff(Integer integer){}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the line of code `Box<Integer> b = new Box(new String("may be"));`
On creation of the new `Box` object is missing about the type Info and assuming as a `Object` class for default.

`Box<String> b = new Box<>(new String());` this is the right way to do so

-------- added --------

In `Object` class's method `getClass()` returns the runtime `Class` object. and when returning, your code `Box<Integer>` makes `getClass()` method to return `Class<Integer>` not `Class<String>`.

You gaved raw type with `new B(new String());` so the compiler passed for the syntax, but while calling `getClass()` it casts inner object `String` to `Integer` and throws the RuntimeException

Comment: I don't read the question as, "how do I fix this?" but rather, "why does a raw type break in this particular way?"