# Java Generics casts strangely

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am using java 8.

I recently came across this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ss = "" + (Test.<Integer>abc(2));
        System.out.println(Test.<Integer>abc(2));
    }
    public static <T> T abc(T a) {
        String s = "adsa";
        return (T) s;
    }
}
```

This does not throw a java.lang.ClassCastException. Why is that?

I always thought `+` and `System.out.println` calls `toString`. But when I try to do that it throws an Exception as expected.

```
String sss = (Test.<Integer>abc(2)).toString();
```

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings, and you will see the answer:  your cast is not “safe.”  Meaning, it is not doing what you think it’s doing.  Specifically, generics are subject to type erasure, meaning they are only a means of enforcing safety at compile time, not runtime.  At runtime, the method doesn’t know `T` is `Integer`.  The compiler translated `(T)` to `(Object)` due to the declaration of `<T>`.

Comment: Relates question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757141/java-raw-type-value-assigned-to-generic-type-run-time-getclss-method-error

Comment: See also [this quite clear answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47548635/6413377) to my question related.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't throw a `ClassCastException` because all generic type information is stripped from the compiled code (a process called [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)). Basically, any type parameter is replaced by `Object`. That's why the first version works. It's also why the code compiles at all. If you ask the compiler to warn about unchecked or unsafe operations with the `-Xlint:unchecked` flag, you'll get a warning about an unchecked cast in the `return` statement of `abc()`.

With this statement:

```
String sss = (Test.<Integer>abc(2)).toString();
```

the story is a bit different. While the type parameter `T` is replaced by `Object`, the calling code gets translated into byte code that explicitly casts the result to `Integer`. It is as if the code were written with a method with signature `static Object abc(Object)` and the statement were written:

```
String sss = ((Integer) Test.abc(Integer.valueOf(2))).toString();
```

That is, not only does the cast inside `abc()` go away due to type erasure, a new cast is inserted by the compiler in the calling code. This cast generates a `ClassCastException` at run time because the object returned from `abc()` is a `String`, not an `Integer`.

Note that the statement

```
String ss = "" + (Test.<Integer>abc(2));
```

doesn't require a cast because the compiler simply feeds the object returned by `abc()` into a string concatenation operation for objects. (The details of how this is done varies with the Java compiler, but it is either a call to a `StringBuilder` append method or, as of Java 9, a call to a method created by `StringConcatFactory`.) The details here don't matter; the point is that the compiler is smart enough to recognize that no cast is needed.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The compiler doesn't care or know about `String.valueOf`. String concatenation compiles to a series of `StringBuilder.append`s. The append [may be called with a string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.String-) if you explicitly called `toString` (might NPE), or [with an object if you didn't](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.Object-). In the latter case, `String.valueOf` is used by `StringBuilder`, but that's an implementation detail.

Comment: @Michael - You're right about that. I was just trying to make the point that the compiler didn't need to insert a cast check into the compiled code; I wasn't trying to explain how the compiler dealt with string concatenation. Unfortunately, in the process I generated a misleading example. I'll see if I can rework that piece of the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Generics disappear at runtime, so a cast to `T` is really just a cast to `Object` (which the compiler will actually just get rid of), so there's no class cast exception.

`abc` is just a method which takes an object and returns an object. `StringBuilder.append(Object)` is the method which is called, as can be seen from the bytecode:

```
...  
16: invokestatic  #7   // Method abc:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
19: invokevirtual #8   // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
...
```

When you do

```
String sss = (Test.<Integer>abc(2)).toString();
```

Then the bytecode is

```
...
 4: invokestatic  #3   // Method abc:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
 7: checkcast     #4   // class java/lang/Integer
10: invokevirtual #5   // Method java/lang/Integer.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
...
```

Your code fails at the [`checkcast` operation](https://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--7.html), which was not present before.